# How to round the edges of a DropdownButton's list?

Tags: flutter

I want to round the edges of a DropdownButton's opened list window that holds the DropDownButtonItems.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a Container and then use the decoration property to add a BoxDecoration, and in it you can specify borderRadius like this:

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
 ),
);
```

Comment: This changes the shape of the **DropDownButton** but it doesn't change the shape of the **list** itself. @Sarvesh Bhatnagar

Comment: @EliasMarrero Have you tried to wrap entire list inside of the container? with the above properties?

Comment: I wrapped the entire DropdownButton @Sarvesh Bhatnagar

Comment: I was going through the documents, it appears to be the case that it is not yet possible to change the edges to be a bit rounded in the drop down. ref. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/DropdownButton.html furthermore, if you really need a dropdown with rounded edges, you can opt for creating your custom dropdown or opt for this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/menu_button